# Incompatibility between 'flushend' and 'lineno' packages!

Tags: two-column, incompatibility, multicol, line-numbering

I have observed when  using `flushend` package to balance the references at the last page, if at the same time the package `lineno`is loaded, the last page of reference will not be displayed.  I have tested using `\twocolumn` document with default package option for `lineno`.

As soon as I remove either `flushend` or `lineno` package definition, the thing go well!
Is there any incompatibility between these two packages?

In the following MWE, the last page will be gone if you include the `lineno` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\twocolumn
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Is there any other way I can balance the columns at the last page without using `flushend` and `balance` and `multicol` packages? `multicol` with `\twocolum` will not result in nice output, if I use `\onecolum` before `\begin{multicols}` it will create new page, which I dont want.

Comment: Please (always) make a small example document that shows the problem.

Comment: Yes, they appear to be incompatible.  Both are meddling with output routines.

Comment: Is there any other way I can balance the columns at the last page without using `flushend` and `balance` packages?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as you observe `flushend` does not work well with `lineno`.  On the other hand, the `lineno` package does include specific code to cope with `multicol`.  So
I suggest you use `mulitcol` for the whole document insead of `\twocolumn`.  To allow space for the line numbers, you  should increase the space between the columns by setting `\columnsep`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Andrew. There are several reasons I prefare `\twocolumn` or `multicol`. `table` and `figure` won't display correctly and need modification. Moreover, the document won't look good after changing to `multicol` which will take quiet a while to fix every part. BTW, is there any way to switch to `\onecolumn` without incurring a page break?!

Comment: I understand.  A command `\myonec` defined as `\makeatletter
\def\myonec{\global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
  \global\@twocolumnfalse
  \col@number \@ne
  \@floatplacement}
\makeatother` will switch to one column without page break, but behaves badly with respect to floats, and I don't see how it helps your situation.