# Separate reference section in IEEE format

Tags: biblatex, vertical-alignment, two-column, ieeeconf

IEEE paper format can be viewed [here](https://www.slideshare.net/sameeeee/ieee-paper-format). In the last page, Reference starts with the end of Acknowledgement. I'm able to do this, used `\balance` before `\printbibliography[title=References]`. Now I want to add some tweak which is something like this: [image: this]

The main idea I want to get is: up to REFERENCE all texts are balanced. Then a fresh start of REFERENCE section on the same page.

[MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/10528761xmqmhzzwhfks#/39305964/): somehow document is not balanced (`lipsum` never used before). Example is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378112/105582).

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=true,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxcitenames=1,
    urldate=long,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@inproceedings{zhu1,
  author =        {Benjamin Zhu and Kai Li and Hugo Patterson},
  booktitle =     {USENIX Conference on File and Storage Technologies
                   (FAST'08)},
  month =         {Feb},
  title =         {Avoiding the Disk Bottleneck in the {D}ata {D}omain
                   Deduplication File System},
  year =          {2008},
}
@article{zhu2,
  author =        {Benjamin Zhu and Kai Li and Hugo Patterson},
  booktitle =     {USENIX Conference on File and Storage Technologies
                   (FAST'08)},
  month =         {Feb},
  title =         {Avoiding the Disk Bottleneck in the {D}ata {D}omain
                   Deduplication File System},
  year =          {2008},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Conferences}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

This demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE conference papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8b and later.

\lipsum[2]

I wish you the best of success.

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here. Citations here \cite{zhu1}.
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here \cite{zhu2}.
\lipsum[1]

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Acknowledgment}
The authors would like to thank...
\lipsum[1]

\balance
\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Even though your question is fairly general and clear without an MWE you would make our lives much easier if you could give an MWE that reproduces the undesirable behaviour reasonably well, so we can test our solutions with your exact set-up.

Comment: Seems like a tough ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strip` from [`cuted`](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/cuted.pdf) package I managed to get similar results. Though, manually I have to add two column environment.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=ieee,
citestyle=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=true,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=1,
urldate=long,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@inproceedings{zhu1,
  author =        {Benjamin Zhu and Kai Li and Hugo Patterson},
  booktitle =     {USENIX Conference on File and Storage Technologies
               (FAST'08)},
  month =         {Feb},
  title =         {Avoiding the Disk Bottleneck in the {D}ata {D}omain
               Deduplication File System},
  year =          {2008},
}
@article{zhu2,
  author =        {Benjamin Zhu and Kai Li and Hugo Patterson},
  booktitle =     {USENIX Conference on File and Storage Technologies
               (FAST'08)},
  month =         {Feb},
  title =         {Avoiding the Disk Bottleneck in the {D}ata {D}omain
               Deduplication File System},
  year =          {2008},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Conferences}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

This demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE conference papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8b and later.

\lipsum[2]

I wish you the best of success.

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here. Citations here \cite{zhu1}.
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here \cite{zhu2}.
\lipsum[1]

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Acknowledgment}
The authors would like to thank...
\lipsum[1]


\begin{strip}\leavevmode\kern15pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \printbibliography[title=References]
\end{multicols}
\end{strip}

\end{document}
```